# Find the sum of amount for particular transasaction type for 2 consecutive days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables 1. Transactions and 2. Transaction type

e.g. of transaction table with dummy data

```
account_key  Transaction_key    date        amount
1                 11          03/22/0219     5000
1                 12          03/23/2019     6000
1                 13          03/22/2019     4000
1                 14          03/23/2019     3000
```

e.g. of Transaction_type table with dummy data

```
transaction_key    transaction_type
11                      in
12                      in
13                      out
14                      out
```

I have to find the ratio of sum of amount for 2 consecutive days of similar transaction type for the same account key. for eg (5000+6000)/(4000+3000)

the database is oracle and datatype is datetime

This is what I have tried

```
select t1.account_key,
       trunc(t1.date),
       sum(t1.amount) as in,
       sum(t2.amount) as out
from   transactions t1 
inner join transactions t2 on t1.accountkey=t2.accountkey
where t1.date between '01-jun-2017' and '30-nov-2017' 
and   t2.date between '01-jun-2017' and '30-nov-2017'
and   t1.transaction_key in (select a.transaction_key 
                             from   transaction_type a
                             where  a.transaction type in 'in')
and   t2.transaction_key in (select b.transaction_key 
                             from   transaction_type b
                             where  b.transaction type in 'out') 
group by t1.account_key,
         trunc(t1.date)
having   max(trunc(t1.date))-min(trunc(t1.date)) = 1
and      max(trunc(t2.date))-min(trunc(t2.date)) = 1
```

Comment: Are there any unique keys on your transactions table?  Can there be more than one transaction key have the same transaction type on the same date for the same account?  That is, for example, is it possible that there are multiple "in" transactions for account_key = 1 on a single date?

Comment: transaction key is the unique key for transaction table.Yes there are more than one transaction key  with similar transaction type

Comment: And do you want only matches from consecutive calendar days or consecutive rows.  That is, if account_key 1 has "in" transactions on the 5th, no activity on the 6th or 7th (maybe a weekend), and then an "out" transaction on the 8th, would those count as "consecutive"?

Comment: Sorry, I made some edits in the transaction_type table. By consecutive dates I mean strictly consecutive that is if first "in" transaction was done on 03/22/2018 then other "in" should either on same day or next day(i.e. 03/23/2018) Similarly the out transaction should on the same day of first "in" transaction or the next day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WITH` clause, also called a "common table expression" or "CTE" to break your problem down into manageable chunks.

Here is one way to do that:

```
WITH txn_by_date AS ( 
  SELECT t.account_key, 
         t.txn_date, 
         tt.transaction_type, 
         sum(t.amount) amount
  FROM   txns t 
  INNER JOIN txn_types tt on tt.transaction_key = t.transaction_key 
  GROUP BY t.account_key, t.txn_date, tt.transaction_type )
SELECT tin.account_key, 
       tin.txn_date, 
       tin.amount amount_in,
       tout.txn_date, 
       tout.amount amount_out,
       tin.amount / tout.amount ratio
FROM   txn_by_date tin
INNER JOIN txn_by_date tout ON tout.txn_date = tin.txn_date + 1 
                           AND tout.transaction_type = 'out'
                           AND tout.account_key = tin.account_key
WHERE tin.transaction_type = 'in';
```

The CTE first computes the total txn amount by account, transaction type, and day.  Once you have that, the main `SELECT` gets each 'in' total, joins it with the 'out' total from the consecutive day, and the computes the ratio.

Here is a full example, with test data (also expressed using the `WITH` clause):

```
with txns (account_key,  Transaction_key,    txn_date,    amount) AS
( 
SELECT 1, 11, TO_DATE('03/22/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 12, TO_DATE('03/23/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 6000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 13, TO_DATE('03/22/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 14, TO_DATE('03/23/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 3000 FROM DUAL ),
txn_types ( transaction_key, transaction_type ) AS 
( 
SELECT 11, 'in' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'out' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 'in' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'out' FROM DUAL ),
txn_by_date AS ( 
  SELECT t.account_key, 
         t.txn_date, 
         tt.transaction_type, 
         sum(t.amount) amount
  FROM   txns t 
  INNER JOIN txn_types tt on tt.transaction_key = t.transaction_key 
  GROUP BY t.account_key, t.txn_date, tt.transaction_type )
SELECT tin.account_key, 
       tin.txn_date, 
       tin.amount amount_in,
       tout.txn_date, 
       tout.amount amount_out,
       tin.amount / tout.amount ratio
FROM   txn_by_date tin
INNER JOIN txn_by_date tout ON tout.txn_date = tin.txn_date + 1 
                           AND tout.transaction_type = 'out'
                           AND tout.account_key = tin.account_key
WHERE tin.transaction_type = 'in';
```

> ```
> +-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-------+
> | ACCOUNT_KEY | TXN_DATE  | AMOUNT_IN | TXN_DATE_1 | AMOUNT_OUT | RATIO |
> +-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-------+
> |           1 | 22-MAR-19 |      9000 | 23-MAR-19  |       9000 |     1 |
> +-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-------+
> ```

#### ALTERNATE VERSION, FOR ANCIENT VERSIONS OF ORACLE

For really old versions of Oracle, you may need to avoid both the `WITH` clause and ANSI-style joins.  Here is the above query rewritten to avoid those features.

```
SELECT tin.account_key, 
       tin.txn_date, 
       tin.amount amount_in,
       tout.txn_date, 
       tout.amount amount_out,
       tin.amount / tout.amount ratio
FROM   ( SELECT t.account_key, 
                t.txn_date, 
                tt.transaction_type, 
                sum(t.amount) amount
         FROM   txns t,
                txn_types tt
         WHERE  tt.transaction_key = t.transaction_key 
         GROUP BY t.account_key, t.txn_date, tt.transaction_type ) tin,
       ( SELECT t.account_key, 
                t.txn_date, 
                tt.transaction_type, 
                sum(t.amount) amount
         FROM   txns t,
                txn_types tt
         WHERE  tt.transaction_key = t.transaction_key 
         GROUP BY t.account_key, t.txn_date, tt.transaction_type ) tout
WHERE tin.transaction_type = 'in'
AND tout.transaction_type(+) = 'out'
AND tout.account_key(+) = tin.account_key;
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I dont have access yet to create temporary table or with clause(as it is giving error missing select statement), is it possible to do it by subquery or joins?

Comment: @Rohit What version of Oracle are you on?

Comment: @Rohit I updated my answer with a version that should work on older versions of Oracle.

Comment: I am using Toad for oracle 12.6

Comment: @Rohit -- Run `select banner from v$version` and update your post with the results so people know what version of Oracle you're working with.  Your version of TOAD doesn't matter much since you can upgrade it easily.

Comment: it is oracle 11g

Comment: Also I tried joining tout and tin the error i am getting is ORA-00904: "TOUT"."EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME": invalid identifier and I ran the script which you updated I am getting same error ORA-00904: "TOUT"."EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME": invalid identifier

Answer (score -1):

I would try to use to Temporary Tables. Store the sums of each in Transaction type in two temp tables, then use them to calculate your ratio. I have not tested this query but this is basically what you are looking for:

```
 CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE as In_TempTable
 Select T2.Transaction_Type, sum(T1.amount) In_Total
 from Transactions T1
 left join Transaction_Type T2 on T2.Transaction_key = T1.Transaction_Key 
 where T1.date between '01-jun-2017' and '30-nov-2017'
      AND T2.Transactio_Type = 'In'
 group by T2.Transaction_Type;

 CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE as Out_TempTable
 Select T2.Transaction_Type, sum(T1.amount) Out_Total
 from Transactions T1
 left join Transaction_Type T2 on T2.Transaction_key = T1.Transaction_Key 
 where T1.date between '01-jun-2017' and '30-nov-2017'
      AND T2.Transactio_Type = 'Out'
 group by T2.Transaction_Type;


 Select Sum(a.In_Total)/Sum(b.Out_Total)
 from In_TempTable a
 Full Outer Join Out_TempTable b on b.Transaction_Type = a.Transaction_Type
```

I would personally change this:

```
T1.date between '01-jun-2017' and '30-nov-2017'
```

To something like this

```
T1.date between startdate and startdate+2
```

Depending on your needs of course and you will have to declare your startdate

Comment: I am working with oracle so dateadd and datediff I guess will not work.T1.date between '01-jun-2017' and '30-nov-2017' is the condition to check for records within that period

Comment: I updated my answer. There are many ways you could have changed the where statement. I added an example above at he end of my answer.

Comment: Private temporary tables are a new feature in Oracle 18c. There is no indication that the OP is using the latest version of Oracle. A